# Sqlite and Excel Pivot Table - ODBC

Tags: python, sqlite, excel, odbc, vba

I'm having some issues with creating a pivot table from an sqlite3 database.  I've made the sqlite connection using the ODBC driver here:
http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/

After I make the excel connection to my sqlite database file, I can make a pivot table no problem **SO LONG** as the database does not contain too many records.  It will work with 1,000,000 rows but Excel gives me errors when I try and load up a 2,000,000 row database.

Below is some sample Pyhton code that generates a sqlite3 database of 1,000,000 records (which works fine) but then when I make a 2,000,000 row database (change `Number_of_Loops = 10` to `Number_of_Loops = 20`) Excel's status bar says "waiting for the query to be executed" then throws these errors:

[image: No microsoft, this was not helpful whatsoever]

[image: Not that helpful either...]

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Open an sqlite connection
db = sqlite3.connect("MyData.sqlite")
cursor = db.cursor()

# Create the table where were gonna put all the data
cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE MyData('Date/Time' TIMESTAMP,
                                        'col1' REAL,
                                        'col2' REAL,
                                        'col3' REAL,
                                        'col4' REAL,
                                        'col5' REAL,
                                        'col6' REAL,
                                        'col7' REAL,
                                        'col8' REAL,
                                        'col9' REAL,
                                        'col10' REAL)
                ''')
# Commit the table creation
db.commit()


# Generate data to put into the table
Number_of_Loops = 10 # Number of loops to go through (total number of records = Number_of_Loops*Records_in_Each_Loop)
Records_in_Each_Loop = 100000 # Number of records to make per loop
for i in range(Number_of_Loops):
    print i
    # How many records to send to the db at once?
    Dateindex = pd.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=Records_in_Each_Loop, freq='H')
    Data = {'col1': np.random.randn(Records_in_Each_Loop),
            'col2': np.random.randn(Records_in_Each_Loop),
            'col3': np.random.randn(Records_in_Each_Loop),
            'col4': np.random.randn(Records_in_Each_Loop),
            'col5': np.random.randn(Records_in_Each_Loop),
            'col6': np.random.randn(Records_in_Each_Loop),
            'col7': np.random.randn(Records_in_Each_Loop),
            'col8': np.random.randn(Records_in_Each_Loop),
            'col9': np.random.randn(Records_in_Each_Loop),
            'col10': np.random.randn(Records_in_Each_Loop)}
    # Create a dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame(Data, index = Dateindex)

    # Have to convert the time stamps into strings for the database
    df['Date/Time'] = df.index
    df['Date/Time'] = df['Date/Time'].apply(str)


    # Send the data to the sqlite database
    df.to_sql(name='MyData', con=db, if_exists='append',index=False)


# Close the database connection
db.close()
```

I'm kind of at a loss for this here.... any one have any idea what might cause this sort of thing?

Comment: Maybe it's using its internal spreadsheet infrastructure to handle the database, and it flips out at 1,048,576 records, which is the maximum number of rows in an Excel table?  Or they have an arbitrary limit of 10^20 records and it's segfaulting?

Answer (score 0):

Excel imposes [limits](http://office.microsoft.com/en-nz/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010342495.aspx) on the size of pivot tables (look about half way down the list).

One of these is that you cannot have more than 1,024,576 unique items per field (this corresponds to the maximum number of rows in an Excel spreadsheet: this might not be a coincidence!).

Comment: I don't think that this is the problem since I'm able to connect to the same data in an access database no problem.

Comment: In that case I don't know the answer.  Possibly just exhausts the available memory, and Access has ways of doing things more efficiently?